# 12V LED remains on

Tags: led, automotive, indicator

I am working on an automotive project where we are using an LED as an indicator for the operation of an engine cooling fan, which is turned on and off automatically by the vehicle's ECM.

The module that activates the fan receives ground as an activation signal, so we connected the ground source of the LED to the wire that activates the module and the hot wire of the LED to a power source on the vehicles fuse box. The problem is that the LED remains lit in a low dim at all times and it only turns brighter when the ECM activates the cooling fan.

We tried installing a relay but the actions reverse and only the LED turns on, but not the cooling fan; is there a simple solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppress noise current on floating LED lead with pull up R.

Comment: Your LED is probably pulling the line up. Does your LED include a series, current-limiting resistor?

Comment: It does not, it is a direct on/off plug and play diode.

Comment: Was it designed for direct 12 VDC use? (Most LEDs, as parts, run off of about 2 V to perhaps as high as 4 V; but they do not run off of 12 V directly.)

Comment: @EdM - (a) Not enough details about the problem with the relay - schematic diagram needed. (b) "*The module that activates the fan receives ground as an activation signal*" Based on the symptoms you describe, I suspect the activation signal may not be as simple as that. Assuming I understand the config correctly (you need to add a diagram!) how did you check whether the ECM output was push-pull or open-drain? How did you check for any pull-ups/pull-downs at the ECM output, and at the fan control module input? IMHO you need to explain *lots* more about your analysis of the relevant i/p & o/p.

Comment: What voltage is that "activation signal" when the fan is *not* on?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a linear current regulator with an enable input.  A PWM input often can be used as an Enable.

You would would turn the LED off an on with the Enable/PWM input.

Something like this: [Infineon TLE4241GM](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE4241GM-DS-v01_03-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30431ddc9372011ebaad49bf7f26&ack=t)

[image]